# ClassList does not work in IE9. need alternative function

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I am unable to run '[W3Schools Accordion with symbols](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_symbol)' in IE9. ClassList does not work in IE9. It gives following error

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'toggle': object is null or undefined
```

**I am not a coder.  I need alternative function, so that I dont need to recreate my 1000 lines static HTML page.**

Here is full code that I need to run in IE9

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\02795';
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #777;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2796";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Accordion with symbols</h2>
<p>In this example we have added a "plus" sign to each button. When the user clicks on the button, the "plus" sign is replaced with a "minus" sign.</p>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you tagged the question with jQuery, you could use `toggleClass()`, like this:

```
$(".accordion").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().toggleClass("show");
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".accordion").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().toggleClass("show");
  });
});
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
button.accordion:after {
  content: '\02795';
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2796";
}
div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
div.panel.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Accordion with symbols</h2>
<p>In this example we have added a "plus" sign to each button. When the user clicks on the button, the "plus" sign is replaced with a "minus" sign.</p>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or without jQuery you could add the required classes on click number 1 and remove the classes on click number 2. Essentially toggling.

This is achieved using the modulus operator (%), which gives you the remainder of the 2 numbers that you are dividing - to determine whether the count (i) is odd or even.

Something like:

```
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].onclick = function () {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        this.classList.addClass("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.addClass("show");
    } else {
        this.classList.removeClass("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.removeClass("show");
    }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery, [you can use the following polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Works for IE 8+

```
/* 
 * classList.js: Cross-browser full element.classList implementation.
 * 2014-07-23
 *
 * By Eli Grey, http://eligrey.com
 * Public Domain.
 * NO WARRANTY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.
 */

/*global self, document, DOMException */

/*! @source http://purl.eligrey.com/github/classList.js/blob/master/classList.js*/

if ("document" in self) {

// Full polyfill for browsers with no classList support
if (!("classList" in document.createElement("_"))) {

(function (view) {

"use strict";

if (!('Element' in view)) return;

var
    classListProp = "classList"
  , protoProp = "prototype"
  , elemCtrProto = view.Element[protoProp]
  , objCtr = Object
  , strTrim = String[protoProp].trim || function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
  }
  , arrIndexOf = Array[protoProp].indexOf || function (item) {
    var
        i = 0
      , len = this.length
    ;
    for (; i < len; i++) {
      if (i in this && this[i] === item) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
  // Vendors: please allow content code to instantiate DOMExceptions
  , DOMEx = function (type, message) {
    this.name = type;
    this.code = DOMException[type];
    this.message = message;
  }
  , checkTokenAndGetIndex = function (classList, token) {
    if (token === "") {
      throw new DOMEx(
          "SYNTAX_ERR"
        , "An invalid or illegal string was specified"
      );
    }
    if (/\s/.test(token)) {
      throw new DOMEx(
          "INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR"
        , "String contains an invalid character"
      );
    }
    return arrIndexOf.call(classList, token);
  }
  , ClassList = function (elem) {
    var
        trimmedClasses = strTrim.call(elem.getAttribute("class") || "")
      , classes = trimmedClasses ? trimmedClasses.split(/\s+/) : []
      , i = 0
      , len = classes.length
    ;
    for (; i < len; i++) {
      this.push(classes[i]);
    }
    this._updateClassName = function () {
      elem.setAttribute("class", this.toString());
    };
  }
  , classListProto = ClassList[protoProp] = []
  , classListGetter = function () {
    return new ClassList(this);
  }
;
// Most DOMException implementations don't allow calling DOMException's toString()
// on non-DOMExceptions. Error's toString() is sufficient here.
DOMEx[protoProp] = Error[protoProp];
classListProto.item = function (i) {
  return this[i] || null;
};
classListProto.contains = function (token) {
  token += "";
  return checkTokenAndGetIndex(this, token) !== -1;
};
classListProto.add = function () {
  var
      tokens = arguments
    , i = 0
    , l = tokens.length
    , token
    , updated = false
  ;
  do {
    token = tokens[i] + "";
    if (checkTokenAndGetIndex(this, token) === -1) {
      this.push(token);
      updated = true;
    }
  }
  while (++i < l);

  if (updated) {
    this._updateClassName();
  }
};
classListProto.remove = function () {
  var
      tokens = arguments
    , i = 0
    , l = tokens.length
    , token
    , updated = false
    , index
  ;
  do {
    token = tokens[i] + "";
    index = checkTokenAndGetIndex(this, token);
    while (index !== -1) {
      this.splice(index, 1);
      updated = true;
      index = checkTokenAndGetIndex(this, token);
    }
  }
  while (++i < l);

  if (updated) {
    this._updateClassName();
  }
};
classListProto.toggle = function (token, force) {
  token += "";

  var
      result = this.contains(token)
    , method = result ?
      force !== true && "remove"
    :
      force !== false && "add"
  ;

  if (method) {
    this[method](token);
  }

  if (force === true || force === false) {
    return force;
  } else {
    return !result;
  }
};
classListProto.toString = function () {
  return this.join(" ");
};

if (objCtr.defineProperty) {
  var classListPropDesc = {
      get: classListGetter
    , enumerable: true
    , configurable: true
  };
  try {
    objCtr.defineProperty(elemCtrProto, classListProp, classListPropDesc);
  } catch (ex) { // IE 8 doesn't support enumerable:true
    if (ex.number === -0x7FF5EC54) {
      classListPropDesc.enumerable = false;
      objCtr.defineProperty(elemCtrProto, classListProp, classListPropDesc);
    }
  }
} else if (objCtr[protoProp].__defineGetter__) {
  elemCtrProto.__defineGetter__(classListProp, classListGetter);
}

}(self));

} else {
// There is full or partial native classList support, so just check if we need
// to normalize the add/remove and toggle APIs.

(function () {
  "use strict";

  var testElement = document.createElement("_");

  testElement.classList.add("c1", "c2");

  // Polyfill for IE 10/11 and Firefox <26, where classList.add and
  // classList.remove exist but support only one argument at a time.
  if (!testElement.classList.contains("c2")) {
    var createMethod = function(method) {
      var original = DOMTokenList.prototype[method];

      DOMTokenList.prototype[method] = function(token) {
        var i, len = arguments.length;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          token = arguments[i];
          original.call(this, token);
        }
      };
    };
    createMethod('add');
    createMethod('remove');
  }

  testElement.classList.toggle("c3", false);

  // Polyfill for IE 10 and Firefox <24, where classList.toggle does not
  // support the second argument.
  if (testElement.classList.contains("c3")) {
    var _toggle = DOMTokenList.prototype.toggle;

    DOMTokenList.prototype.toggle = function(token, force) {
      if (1 in arguments && !this.contains(token) === !force) {
        return force;
      } else {
        return _toggle.call(this, token);
      }
    };

  }

  testElement = null;
}());

}

}
```